# Java: How can I use jsoup to extract headlines from a news page?

Tags: java, jsoup, extract

I want to get the first headline and print it. So far, I have looked through the HTML and found a way to search for the headlines.

```
data-pb-placeholder="Write headline here"
```

That code usually precedes any headline I want. So far I have...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.washingtonpost.com").get();
Element headline = doc.select("headline").first();
System.out.println(headline);
```

It is only outputting null. I'm not sure how I can search through the doc and find headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the headlines are all under `<div class="headline">`.  You can use [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to target these and extract their text node.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.washingtonpost.com").get();

    for (Element headline : doc.select("div.headline"))
        System.out.println(headline.text());
```